# Why doesn't my status of the order show up when I type in my email?

Tags: html, go

I am making an pizza website and I am working on the status of the order.
The order is working, but if i type my email in the input place, it doesn't show my status.

The HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
        <p>Emailadres <input type="email" name="statuscheck"></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Verzend">

     </form>
     {{ . }}
```

The Handler:

```
func statusHandler(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
log.Println("Viewing status")

// maak een html template object aan
statuschecktemplate, _ := template.ParseFiles("./templates/status.htm")

PizzaBestellingen, _ := LoadBestellingenFromMap()

var data string

for _, value := range PizzaBestellingen {
    for _, value := range value {
        if value.Email == request.FormValue("statuscheck") {
            data = value.Status
        }
    }
}
fmt.Println(data)
// genereer de html met de lijst van pizzas
// deze worden automatisch teruggestuurd naar de browser
statuschecktemplate.Execute(writer, data)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looking at its definition,

```
func LoadBestellingenFromMap() (map[string][]Klant, error) {
```

`LoadBestellingenFromMap` returns a `map` to a *`slice`* of `Klant`s, not just one.

You might try something like:

```
for _, values := range PizzaBestellingen {
  for _, value := range Values {
    if value.Email == request.FormValue("statuscheck") {
        data = value.Status
    }
  }
}
```

It's possible you'll also have to reconsider the logic of your algorithm ( you could get more than one such `Email`), but that is already be the case, since you were already iterating across `PizzaBestellingen` anyway.  Keep it in mind if it's possible more than one such email would match.

Comment: no problem.  If this answers your question, you should Accept the answer